# Default PHP echo if the content to return is empty

Tags: php, header, echo

Let's see if I can explain myself. I need to return a default HTML template as a fallback operation if the content to return from the server is empty. It should look like this:

```html
<?php

    // Lots of code here

    // Here I could echo something
    // echo "Welcome world!";
    // but I will not so no text would be returned but ...

    // in this case I have this fallback function that will only be fired if
    // no text has been outputted by any mean before
    // fallback_template();

    fallback_template() {
        echo "<html><head><title>Empty</title></head><body>No content</body></html>";
    }
```

I have tried using `headers_sent()` to check but it doesn't work. Is there any way to achieve it or is it beyond PHP's possibilities? I need it for *browserSync*, so it remains active always.

Comment: If `headers_sent()` always returns true even with no echo, then you might have some whitespace before `<?php` which is being sent as output, causing the headers to be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
        ob_start();
        // Lots of code here

        // Here I could echo something
        // echo "Welcome world!";
        // but I will not so no text would be returned but ...

        // in this case I have this fallback function that will only be fired if
        // no text has been outputted by any mean before
        // fallback_template();

        fallback_template() {
            // buffer is empty nothing was sent to client (using print, echo or an error happened)
            if(ob_get_length() == 0 ) {            
                echo "<html><head><title>Empty</title></head><body>No content</body></html>";
            }
        }
```